# I need to extract string from a text in dataframe in pythone

Tags: python, string

I have Data frame contains a column as below with 4000 rows i need to extract a string like :

Action-Adventure-Fantasy-Science Fiction

from the hereunder text

```
'[{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}, {"id": 14, "name": "Fantasy"}, {"id": 878, "name": "Science Fiction"}]'
```

Comment: This is JSON. How did you create the DataFrame in the first place? You can always process the column and parse the JSON, but I guess you may be better doing something different when creating the  df in the first place. Also, you better show [mre], i.e. incl. sample dataframe.

Comment: I have a .CSV file contain data about movies I have a column all of it just like I uploaded above .I need to extract the genres of movie from this text format and create new row with useful genres only

Comment: Exactly my point - you have a csv file and you crate the dataframe in a way that result in having some json in a column. Where the csv comes from/how is created, what is the format of the csv file?

Comment: it's a normal csv file but there is a three column with the same format "json"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question, it seems that you have this string/list of dict embedded data *per row* in your dataframe.

I've coded up an example that might help:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
df = pd.DataFrame(['[{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}, {"id": 14, "name": "Fantasy"}, {"id": 878, "name": "Science Fiction"}]'], columns=['x'])
```

I've made a custom function to apply to each row of data. It may not be the most elegant but hopefully it's easy to understand.

```
def collect_names(data_dict):
    name_list = [dic["name"] for dic in data_dict]
    return '-'.join(name_list)
```

and finally,

```
df["names"] = df['x'].apply(lambda row: collect_names(json.loads(row)))
```

returns ... 'Action-Adventure-Fantasy-Science Fiction' per row in your dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

That is JSON rather than a dataframe. Use the `json` module:

```
import json
s = '[{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}, {"id": 14, "name": "Fantasy"}, {"id": 878, "name": "Science Fiction"}]'
'-'.join(d['name'] for d in json.loads(s))

#evaluates to 'Action-Adventure-Fantasy-Science Fiction'
```